# What is the precise meaning of $c_\infty \cong c_0 \oplus \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, direct-sum

I am supposed to show that $c_\infty \cong c_0 \oplus \mathbb{C}$, where
$$
c_\infty := \{(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}| a_n \in \mathbb{C}, a_n \to a \in \mathbb{C}\}, \\
c_0 := \{(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}| a_n \in \mathbb{C}, a_n \to 0\},
$$
so $c_\infty$ is the space of convergent sequences with values in $\mathbb{C}$ and $c_0$ the space of null sequences.
I am confused by a view things:

1. What does $c_0 \oplus \mathbb{C}$ mean? We defined a direct sum as follows: If $M$ and $N$ are linear subspaces of a linear space $X$, we write $X = M \oplus N$ iff $M+N = X$ and $M \cap N = \{0\}$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is not a subspace from $\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$, the direct sum does not make sense. Of course, one can identify $\mathbb{C}$ with the space of all constant sequences, say $c$. Then we have actually have $c_\infty = c_0 \oplus c$, right?
2. So, when we write $c_\infty \cong c_0 \oplus \mathbb{C}$, do we actually just mean  $c \cong \mathbb{C}$ and $c_\infty = c_0 \oplus c$ or has $c_\infty \cong c_0 \oplus \mathbb{C}$ another precise mathematical meaning?

Comment: Exactly, I am not sure what I have to prove, since my lecture notes do not, at least to me, suggest what could be meant, by such a thing as $c_0 \oplus \mathbb{C}$. So, my question was if this means that I **have to** identify $c$ with $\mathbb{C}$ and subsequently show that $c_\infty = c_0 \oplus c$?

Comment: Yes, I deleted it.

Comment: In $c_\infty \cong c_0 \oplus \mathbb{C},$ the RHS is an *external* direct sum. But yes, you can argue it is isomorphic to your *internal* direct sum $ c_0 \oplus c.$ Anyway, you are asked to explicit some isomorphism.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Anna Bauval so I have to view $c_0 \oplus \mathbb{C}$ as an external direct sum of two vector spaces and $c_0 \oplus c$ as an internal direct sum of subspaces?
@ Shaun Should I reformulate the post, so it consist of only one question?

Comment: @julian2000P Consider some $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and how $c_0 + z$ relates to $c_\infty$ Now us that to notion to construct the isomorphism.